# Recyclerview Drag and Drop onTouch functionality not dismissed

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to follow along with this tutorial to implement Drag and Drop functionality: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.ovb9pairq and have run into a problem where the from position **sometimes** remains touched. I haven't found a way to narrow down the cause of the sometimes here but it happens much more frequently than not. This causes me to either have to set a new adapter or click one of the UI elements to reset it and continue drag and drop operations.

I think these images may help clarify.. in the second notice the from position remains selected even though I am not touching the UI item. Can anyone point me into the right direction to understand why the touch remains after the drag and drop is ended?

initial

[image: initial setup]

After dragging d into b's position

[image: After dragging d up to b position]

adapter code:

```
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
  mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(viewHolder);
  }
  return false;
  }
});

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
  this.dataset.remove(position);
  notifyItemRemoved(position);
  notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(this.dataset.size()) + " is my dataset size");
}

@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
  Collections.swap(this.dataset, fromPosition, toPosition);
  notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
  return true;
}
```

ViewHolder code:

```
public ItemViewHolder(View v) {
  super(v);
  cardText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected() {
  itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}

@Override
public void onItemClear() {
  itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
}
```

Comment: Update here: I updated the callback in the example code linked above from

    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

to 


    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

with some success

Comment: still problems?

Comment: Sorry.. I hadn't checked up here in a while. Disabling the long touch fixed my issue and I kind of settled on that. I am still not totally clear on why it fixes the issue though.

Comment: Hey, thanks! IsLongPressDragEnabled () {return false; } work for me!!